# Endeca Stratify relevance support for Thai Language

Tags: oracle, endeca, oracle-commerce

Will stratify relevance algorithm supports languages other than English? I have an requirement where the value of the property will be in Thai language and I have to boost the records based on this property. 
The property will be `p_name:  กะหล่ำปลีหัวใจ`.
I have tried by specifying in Ntx query parameter

`Ntx=mode+matchallpartial+rel+stratify(collection()/record[p_name="กะหล่ำปลีหัวใจ"],*)`

The above one does not work, so i tried encoding the entire string

`stratify(collection()%2Frecord%5Bp_name%3D%22%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B0%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%A5%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%B3%E0%B8%9B%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B5%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%A7%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%88%22%5D%2C*)%0A`

This method also does not work, I don't see the records getting boosted.

Also I have enabled the property for filtering and search. Dgraph language --lang setting is also specified as "th".

Should I enable any extra setting to support thai language. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Endeca is a really niche product. You should ask your question on the Oracle Technet forum dedicated to Endeca. [Find it here](https://community.oracle.com/community/business_intelligence/information_discovery/endeca_information_discovery)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Endeca Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E66321_01/mdex.6-5-2/EndecaMDEXDev/html/rbdv_recboost_sorting.xmlsection_9A84CCA4BD6A410EB569E826667D47D5.html) you must prepend `Endeca` to the module name.  I have not tested the below but believe it should work:

`Ntx=mode+matchallpartial+rel+Endeca.stratify(collection()/record[p_name="กะหล่ำปลีหัวใจ"],*)`